# Spring Data DomainClassConverter not working (in combination with Java Config)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup the Spring Data/JPA DomainClassConverter to automatically convert (String) id's to the domain classes itself.

My project is uses Java Config (so no xml).

In my WebConfig I have currently:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new DomainClassConverter<DefaultFormattingConversionService>((DefaultFormattingConversionService) registry));
    }
}
```

This seems to hook up the DomainClassConverter successfully as I can see it inside the conversion service when printing that:

```
ConversionService converters =
  ..<default converters>..
  org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter@6ea4ce0d, org.springframework.core.convert.support.IdToEntityConverter@5d3f03b, org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter@1d40b47a
```

But when submitting a nested form (Order with Customer ref) the Customer is not converted automatically and hence I get a:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.mycomp.domain.Customer for property customer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.mycomp.domain.Customer] for property customer: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DomainClassConverter` should be declared as a bean (because it's `ApplicationContextAware`), and it registers itself in `ConversionService` automatically, so that you don't need to register it manually:

```
@Bean @Autowired
public DomainClassConverter domainClassConverter(ConversionService cs) {
    return new DomainClassConverter(cs);
}
```

Comment: An example of this can be seen in https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-book/blob/rest-extension/rest/src/main/java/com/oreilly/springdata/rest/RestWebApplicationInitializer.java

Comment: Yes thanks this works partially now. The String id to Domain class works. However when printing a Order domain class in a jsp view I get a `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.ManyToOne org.mycomp.domain.Customer to type java.lang.String` error. Am I still missing something here?

Comment: That's the way it's intended to work. The converter's purpose is to ease binding to a Spring MVC controller or a Spring bean in general. I don't think it's reasonable to default the common toString() representation of an entity to a string representation of its id. It shouldn't be a too big issue to just reference ${entity.id} instead.

Comment: Forget my last comment, it had nothing to do with DomainClassConverter as it gave the same error without having it configured. Problem was related to `<spring:eval expression="order.customer" />`. That spring:eval tag causing the problem. `${order.customer}` works fine.

Comment: `@Bean
public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter(FormattingConversionService conversionService) {
 return new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(conversionService);
}` is the variant I'm using now.

Answer (score -1):

The exception is telling you that you need a custom converter to turn a String into a Customer.  You'll have to tokenize the input and map it into Customer fields.  That's true for all your domain classes.

A Google search also lead me to a thread in the Spring forum:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?122944-Help-with-DomainClassConverter-configuration

It suggests that there might be a bug, depending on which version of Spring you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @duffymo. However I'm using latest Spring and Spring Data and as Oliver Gierke it should be working in these versions.